# Unicorn Continuous Reaping on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, unicorn

Moving from Thin to Unicorn.  Unicorn works fine on my development machine (Mac OSX), but fails on Heroku with the following message over and over (different PID, different worker number between 0 and 2) `reaped #<Process::Status: pid 564 exit 1> worker=0`. No other messages in the log indicating what the problem is. What does this message indicate and how can I troubleshoot it?

```
Procfile:
  web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb

Unicorn.rb:
  worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 3)
  timeout 15
  preload_app true

  before_fork do |server, worker|

    Signal.trap 'TERM' do
      puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
      Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
    end

    defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  end  

  after_fork do |server, worker|

    Signal.trap 'TERM' do
      puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to sent QUIT'
    end

    defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
```

Comment: I am hitting the same issue .. did you find a solution?  The suggestion from blotto below did not work for me.

Comment: What seemed to fix it (I was trying a lot of things) was commenting out the "preload_app true" line. Let me know if it works for you and I'll make it an official answer.

Answer (score 0):

this is a very late reply, if still open, can you try the following, be sure to have `RAILS_ENV1 properly set on Heroku

```
 web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -E $RAILS_ENV -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```